# Почему при парсинге сайта выдаёт None (bs4)

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

Почему при парсинге сайта программа не может найти `b-page__container`? Вместо этого программа выдаёт `None`.

Как это исправить?

https://yandex.ru/pogoda/region/225

```
import requests  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://yandex.ru/pogoda/region/225"
responce = requests.get(link).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(responce, 'lxml')

towns = soup.find("div", class_="b-page__container")
print(towns)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если выдаёт None значит элемент не найден. Некоторые элементы могут динамически подгружаться, чтобы убедиться, что элемент присутствует попробуйте загрузить полученный код страницы в файл, а после постарайтесь найти этот элемент уже в файле.

Answer (score 0):

Для того, что бы получить данные, вам надо передать словарь `headers` вместе с запросом, в этом заголовке достаточно передать ключ `"Cookie": "j=-h9......"`. Эти данные берёте во вкладке `Network` Вашего браузера в `Request Headers`.
Вот пример рабочего кода, Вам надо только отредактировать `headers` подставив ваши данные из браузера:

```
import requests  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


link = "https://yandex.ru/pogoda/region/225"
headers = {
        "Cookie": "ТУТ ДОЛЖНЫ БЫТЬ ВАШИ ДАННЫЕ Cookie из БРАУЗЕРА",
    }

session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update(headers)

responce = session.get(link).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(responce, 'html.parser')

regions = soup.find("div", "b-page__container")
place_list = regions.find_all("div", "place-list")
for place in place_list:
    regions_names = place.find_all("a")
    for a in regions_names:
        print(f"Название региона: {a.text}")
```

Вот, что возвращает этот код:

```
...
Название региона: Чукотский автономный округ
Название региона: Ямало-Ненецкий автономный округ
Название региона: Ярославская область
```